# REST API or CSOM JS GetList return URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api

I need to get **url** list, Title is ready, Title is not equals url.

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var website = clientContext.get_web();
var list = website.get_lists().getByTitle("ListTitle");
```

How to get url list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the URL of the list as below:

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var website = clientContext.get_web();
var list = website.get_lists().getByTitle("ListTitle");
var rootFolder = list.get_rootFolder();
clientContext.load(list);
clientContext.load(rootFolder);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    console.log(list.get_rootFolder().get_serverRelativeUrl());
},
function (sender, args) {
     console.log('error');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Gautam, i understand list.get_rootFolder() -> get_serverRelativeUrl() !!!!